# R xgb.importance shows error - "feature_names has less elements than there are features used in the model"

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm exploring the XGBoost in R. 
After training the model, I wanted to see the feature-importance data.

```
xgb.importance(model = bst)
```

The above call shows the following error. What might be wrong?

```
Error in xgb.model.dt.tree(feature_names = feature_names, text = model_text_dump, : feature_names has less elements than there are features used in the model
```

PN - I checked the following section of the xgboost lib code, but still couldn't figure out the actual issue.

```
# assign feature_names when available
  if (!is.null(feature_names)) {
    if (length(feature_names) <= max(as.numeric(td$Feature), na.rm = TRUE))
      stop("feature_names has less elements than there are features used in the model")
    td[isLeaf == FALSE, Feature := feature_names[as.numeric(Feature) + 1] ]
  }
```

Ref - https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/R/xgb.model.dt.tree.R

I see that the `nfeatures` variable of the trained model is same as the number of features passed to this model.

Answer (score 1):

Dose your model have `feature_names` function?
Perhaps try `xgb.importance(feature_names=colnames(bst$feature_names), model = bst)`. Works for me.